# Is there a way to merge air with apk in a combined package?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, command-line, air, apk

I have a game, and I want to include the Adobe Air in the apk so the user has it when they download my game. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Sounds like you want the so called "captive runtime".

Comment: Yes, how can I do this? Will this make my game laggy if combined?

Comment: I found out how to do it in command line, it works, but when I put it on my phone it turns out to be way bigger than the actual apk size on my desktop with air. APK with the captive runtime on desktop is 12 Mb, on phone it is 31 Mb...@LarsBlåsjö